# Use fontawesome icons in ECharts markArea title

Tags: javascript, echarts

Following this example:

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-sections

I was wondering if there is a way of including font-awesome icons in the title of the `markArea` in **ECharts**?

This is defined in:

```js
series: {
    markArea: {
      data: [
        [
          name: '' // define title here
        ]
      ],
    },
  },
```

I have tried different things, but it looks like that `name` is always coerced into a string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `echarts-gl` library. First you have to download icons locally. See the documentation and examples on this. You have to first create a new `image` object. See this as an example. This is not adding icons as you asked. But this can serve you as an example. [ECharts-GL](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=image-to-bar3d&gl=1&theme=dark)